# Drag a button in OSX 10.8 SDK/objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsbutton

I started using objective-c *today* in order to develop an app for OSX (mountain lion).
I have a bunch of buttons that I would like to drag them into some other object, for instance a text field. I followed the tutorials on apple's dev site, but I wans't able to get the drag part working (the drop part works, for instance, I can drag a file from finder into a text file and show its path).

I started by creating a NSButton subclass:
`@interface mp3OCDDraggableButton : NSButton`

and implemented the methods as described in: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Introduction/Intro.html

but the thing doest move!

I put some log messages in mouseDown:, which I can see in, but not if I replace it by mouseDragged: - does this tells me anything?

Can anyone post a simple example with this functionality? I couldn't find anything that works :\

many thanks in advance!

This is the code I have so far for the draggable button. Pretty much the same as in the tutorial.

```
//myDraggableButton.h

@interface myDraggableButton : NSButton <NSDraggingSource, NSPasteboardItemDataProvider>
@end
```

and

```
//myDraggableButton.m

#import "myDraggableButton.h"

@implementation myDraggableButton

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent:(NSEvent*)event
{

    NSLog(@"mouseDown");

    NSPasteboardItem *pbItem = [NSPasteboardItem new];
    [pbItem setDataProvider:self forTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSPasteboardTypeString, nil]];
    NSDraggingItem *dragItem = [[NSDraggingItem alloc] initWithPasteboardWriter:pbItem];
    NSRect draggingRect = self.bounds;
    [dragItem setDraggingFrame:draggingRect contents:[self image]];
    NSDraggingSession *draggingSession = [self beginDraggingSessionWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dragItem] event:event source:self];
    draggingSession.animatesToStartingPositionsOnCancelOrFail = YES;
    draggingSession.draggingFormation = NSDraggingFormationNone;
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:(NSDraggingContext)context
{
    switch (context) {
        case NSDraggingContextOutsideApplication:
            return NSDragOperationCopy;
        case NSDraggingContextWithinApplication:
        default:
            return NSDragOperationCopy;
            break;
    }
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)pasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)sender item:(NSPasteboardItem *)item provideDataForType:(NSString *)type
{
    if ( [type compare: NSPasteboardTypeTIFF] == NSOrderedSame ) {
        [sender setData:[[self image] TIFFRepresentation] forType:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF];
    } else if ( [type compare: NSPasteboardTypePDF] == NSOrderedSame ) {
        [sender setData:[self dataWithPDFInsideRect:[self bounds]] forType:NSPasteboardTypePDF];
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Please post your code. It's nearly impossible to know where to even start without knowing what you've written.

Comment: You haven't implemented a `mouseDown:` method. The event-handler method you have implemented is `mouseDown::`, taking two arguments, the variables for which you've labeled `theEvent` and `event`. Nothing sends you such a message, so that method will never be called; conversely, you will receive a `mouseDown:` message (with one argument), but you've implemented no method in which to respond to it. Remove the “`theEvent:(NSEvent *)`” part (leaving “`mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event`”) to fix that problem.

Answer (score 3):

I apologize for the necromancy, but I stumbled across this question while trying to implement this myself and would like to share the answer because it might be useful to others.

This solution uses categories on `NSActionCell` and `NSControl` because I needed to be able to drag multiple control types, not just buttons. You can adapt this to your needs/classes.

I have commented out code relating to a workaround hack for an undesired fade animation when hiding/unhiding the controls. I fiddled with implicit animations and the like, but couldnt figure out a better way. The hack does work nicely, but I left the window implementation code out.

```
@implementation NSControl (DragControl)

- (NSDraggingSession*)beginDraggingSessionWithDraggingCell:(NSActionCell <NSDraggingSource> *)cell event:(NSEvent*) theEvent
{
    NSImage* image = [self imageForCell:cell];
    NSDraggingItem* di = [[NSDraggingItem alloc] initWithPasteboardWriter:image];
    NSRect dragFrame = [self frameForCell:cell];
    dragFrame.size = image.size;
    [di setDraggingFrame:dragFrame contents:image];

    NSArray* items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:di];

    [self setHidden:YES];
    return [self beginDraggingSessionWithItems:items event:theEvent source:cell];
}

- (NSRect)frameForCell:(NSCell*)cell
{
    // override in multi-cell cubclasses!
    return self.bounds;
}

- (NSImage*)imageForCell:(NSCell*)cell
{
    return [self imageForCell:cell highlighted:[cell isHighlighted]];
}

- (NSImage*)imageForCell:(NSCell*)cell highlighted:(BOOL) highlight
{
    // override in multicell cubclasses to just get an image of the dragged cell.
    // for any single cell control we can just make sure that cell is the controls cell

    if (cell == self.cell || cell == nil) { // nil signifies entire control
                                            // basically a bitmap of the control
                                            // NOTE: the cell is irrelevant when dealing with a single cell control
        BOOL isHighlighted = [cell isHighlighted];
        [cell setHighlighted:highlight];

        NSRect cellFrame = [self frameForCell:cell];

        // We COULD just draw the cell, to an NSImage, but button cells draw their content
        // in a special way that would complicate that implementation (ex text alignment).
        // subclasses that have multiple cells may wish to override this to only draw the cell
        NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:cellFrame];
        NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rep.size];

        [self cacheDisplayInRect:cellFrame toBitmapImageRep:rep];
        [image addRepresentation:rep];
        // reset the original cell state
        [cell setHighlighted:isHighlighted];
        return image;
    }
    // cell doesnt belong to this control!
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark NSDraggingDestination
// message forwarding doesnt work for NSDraggingDestination methods
// because NSView implements empty methods for the protocol
/*
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    return [self.cell draggingEntered:sender];
}

- (void)draggingExited:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    [self.cell draggingExited:sender];
}

- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    return [self.cell prepareForDragOperation:sender];
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    return [self.cell performDragOperation:sender];
}

- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    return [self.cell concludeDragOperation:sender];
}
*/
- (void)draggingEnded:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    // implement whatever you want to do here.
    [self setHidden:NO];
}

@end


static NSPoint _dragImageOffset;
@implementation NSActionCell (DragCell)

- (void)setControlView:(NSView *)view
{
    // this is a bit of a hack, but the easiest way to make the control dragging work.
    // force the control to accept image drags.
    // the control will forward us the drag destination events via our DragControl category

    [view registerForDraggedTypes:[NSImage imagePasteboardTypes]];
    [super setControlView:view];
}

- (BOOL)trackMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent inRect:(NSRect)cellFrame ofView:(NSView *)controlView untilMouseUp:(BOOL)untilMouseUp
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    NSPoint currentPoint = theEvent.locationInWindow;
    BOOL done = NO;
    BOOL trackContinously = [self startTrackingAt:currentPoint inView:controlView];

    BOOL mouseIsUp = NO;
    NSEvent *event = nil;
    while (!done)
    {
        NSPoint lastPoint = currentPoint;

        event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseUpMask|NSLeftMouseDraggedMask)
                                   untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]
                                      inMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode
                                     dequeue:YES];

        if (event)
        {
            currentPoint = event.locationInWindow;

            // Send continueTracking.../stopTracking...
            if (trackContinously)
            {
                if (![self continueTracking:lastPoint
                                         at:currentPoint
                                     inView:controlView])
                {
                    done = YES;
                    [self stopTracking:lastPoint
                                    at:currentPoint
                                inView:controlView
                             mouseIsUp:mouseIsUp];
                }
                if (self.isContinuous)
                {
                    [NSApp sendAction:self.action
                                   to:self.target
                                 from:controlView];
                }
            }

            mouseIsUp = (event.type == NSLeftMouseUp);
            done = done || mouseIsUp;

            if (untilMouseUp)
            {
                result = mouseIsUp;
            } else {
                // Check if the mouse left our cell rect
                result = NSPointInRect([controlView
                                        convertPoint:currentPoint
                                        fromView:nil], cellFrame);
                if (!result)
                    done = YES;
            }

            if (done && result && ![self isContinuous])
                [NSApp sendAction:self.action
                               to:self.target
                             from:controlView];
            else {
                done = YES;
                result = YES;

                // this initiates the control drag event using NSDragging protocols
                NSControl* cv = (NSControl*)self.controlView;
                NSDraggingSession* session = [cv beginDraggingSessionWithDraggingCell:self
                                                                                event:theEvent];
                // _dragImageOffset = [cv convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
                // Note that you will get an ugly flash effect when the image returns if this is set to yes
                // you can work around it by setting NO and faking the release by animating an NSWindowSubclass with the image as the content
                // create the window in the drag ended method for NSDragOperationNone
                // there is [probably a better and easier way around this behavior by playing with view animation properties.
                session.animatesToStartingPositionsOnCancelOrFail = YES;
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}

#pragma mark - NSDraggingSource Methods
- (NSDragOperation)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:(NSDraggingContext)context
{
    switch(context) {
        case NSDraggingContextOutsideApplication:
            return NSDragOperationNone;
            break;

        case NSDraggingContextWithinApplication:
        default:
            return NSDragOperationPrivate;
            break;
    }
}
/*
- (void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
{
    DragAnimationWindow* dw = [DragAnimationWindow sharedAnimationWindow];
    NSControl* cv = (NSControl*)self.controlView;

    NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithPasteboard:session.draggingPasteboard];
    [dw setupDragAnimationWith:cv usingDragImage:image];
    [image release];
    NSRect frame = [cv frameForCell:self];
    frame = [cv convertRect:frame toView:nil];
    [dw setFrame:[cv.window convertRectToScreen:frame] display:NO];
}
*/
- (void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session endedAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation
{
    /*
    if (operation == NSDragOperationNone) {
        DragAnimationWindow* dw = [DragAnimationWindow sharedAnimationWindow];
        NSRect frame = dw.frame;

        NSPoint start = screenPoint;
        start.y += _dragImageOffset.y;
        start.x -= _dragImageOffset.x;

        [dw setFrameTopLeftPoint:start];
        [dw animateToFrame:frame];
    }*/
    // now tell the control view the drag ended so it can do any cleanup it needs
    // this is somewhat hackish
    [self.controlView draggingEnded:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: I've used your code in [Vindo](https://github.com/vindo-app/vindo/blob/7f91c0acb6e3def634a27fced2c12e60e64cc9b9/Vindo/StartMenuButtonCell.m#L56-L122). Thought you'd want to know.

Comment: @tbodt Nice! I'm always pleased when something I've done is helpful to others. Even better when its something hard to find information on. Cool project BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Could the problem be that you're calling `-setDataProvider:forTypes:` with `NSPasteboardTypeString` but your `-pasteboard:item:provideDataForType:` does nothing when passed that type?