# Drag and drop function swift OSX

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, drag-and-drop

This is a bit complex but I hope that someone can help me.
I am trying to build a drag and drop function for my OSX application.

[image]

This is how it is looking at the moment.
So there is just a single textfield which the user can drag and drop around the view. It is simple enough with just one textfield but if there are several textfields it is getting complicated and I don't know how to approach.
This is what I currently have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var test: NSTextField!

@IBAction override func mouseDragged(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    NSCursor.closedHandCursor().set()
    var event_location = theEvent.locationInWindow

    test.frame.origin.x = event_location.x - 192
    test.frame.origin.y = event_location.y
}
```

Test is the name of my NSTextField. I know the name of it so it is simple to move it arround. But if the user adds more textfields (see on the left pane) then I don't know how to address this textfield because I have no name of it (like "test" for the first input).

I am adding the textfields via this code:

```
    let input = NSTextField(frame: CGRectMake(width, height, 100, 22))
    self.MainView.addSubview(input)
```

How can I determine which textfield (if there are multiple on the view) was selected and then move the appropriate via drag and drop?

**The drag and drop is working for that single static textfield**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have prepared a sample app, so consider this:

https://github.com/melifaro-/DraggableNSTextFieldSample

The idea is to introduce `SelectableTextField` which inherits `NSTextField`. `SelectableTextField` provides facility for subscription of interested listener on text field selection event. It has `didSelectCallback` block variable, where you need to set you handling code. Something like this:

```
textField.didSelectCallback = { (textField) in
    //this peace of code will be performed once mouse down event
    //was detected on the text field
    self.currentTextField = textField
}
```

By using mentioned callback mechanism, once text field selected, we can store it in `currentTextField` variable. So that when `mouseDragged` function of `ViewController` is called we are aware of `currentTextField` and we can handle it appropriatelly. In case of sample app we need adjust `currentTextField` origin according drag event shift. Hope it became better now.

P.S. `NSTextField` is opened for inheriting from it, so you can freely use our SelectableTextField everywhere where you use NSTextField, including Interface Builder.

**EDIT**

I have checked out your sample. Unfortuantly I am not able to commit /create pull request into you repository, so find my suggestion here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    didButtonSelectCallback = { (button) in

        if let currentButton = self.currentButton {

            currentButton.highlighted = !currentButton.highlighted

            if currentButton == button {
                self.currentButton = nil
            } else {
                self.currentButton = button
            }
        } else {
            self.currentButton = button
        }

        button.highlighted = !button.highlighted
    }

    addButtonAtRandomePlace()
    addButtonAtRandomePlace()

    didButtonSelectCallback(button: addButtonAtRandomePlace())
}

override func mouseDragged(theEvent: NSEvent) {

    guard let button = currentButton else {
        return
    }

    NSCursor.closedHandCursor().set()

    button.frame.origin.x += theEvent.deltaX
    button.frame.origin.y -= theEvent.deltaY
}

private func addButtonAtRandomePlace() -> SelectableButton {

    let viewWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width
    let viewHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height

    let x = CGFloat(rand() % Int32((viewWidth - ButtonWidth)))
    let y = CGFloat(rand() % Int32((viewHeight - ButtonHeight)))

    let button = SelectableButton(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight))
    button.setButtonType(NSButtonType.ToggleButton)
    button.alignment = NSCenterTextAlignment
    button.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.RoundedBezelStyle
    button.didSelectCallback = didButtonSelectCallback
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    return button
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Could you just edit your answer and explain the steps you made so that I can understand it? Like the class for the NSTextfield and how the SelectableTextField works?

Comment: Thanks again, tried everything out and it worked as expected. I have just one question left, am I also abel to drag around a button or other objects? Check out my sample app in which I tried to make it with a button. Can you tell me why it is not working? https://github.com/tsafadi/DraggableButton

Comment: Could you check out my answer bellow **EDIT**? I already replied there. Sorry that I did not comment here, below the answer.

Comment: Thanks, got it working! Is it also possible to drag the button right away? Like at the moment you have to click on it and then drag it around with the second click. And the drag and drop is not working if I am holding the mouseDown event right inside the button. The button must be selected and the mouseDown event must be outside the button. Is there also a solution in which you can drag the button with the mouseDown event inside the button?

Comment: That's feasible. I found possible solution and tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866029/6197308. I have updated my app on github, so you can check it out. That's code in Obj-C, hope it won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reference unfortunately I am not into objective-c development. Will try to translate the code into swift.

Comment: It is working pretty good but there are a few things left which are not quite as I want them to be. The OSX development is very different from iOS development from which I come. The drag and drop should work as in other OS applications like Sketch.

Comment: I also came from iOS - agree that UI development for OS X really differs with iOS.